# Click event on checkbox not handled because of CSS animation

Tags: html, css, checkbox, event-handling, webkit-animation

I have an **input** and a **checkbox**, when the input is focused it display some information under it.

The problem is : when those information are displayed if I click on the checkbox it hides the information (because my input is not focused anymore) but the checkbox is not checked.

Here is a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FlCaFV0PfZpIiArVpyjQ?p=preview) which reproduce this behavior.

Is there a way to make the `checkbox` checked in this scenario ?

**EDIT :**

I think the problem is because the input loose the focus on the event `mousedown` and the checkbox is checked on the event `mouseup` (or maybe `click`) so when the `mouseup` event is fired the input has already lost the focus so the message under it is hidden and the checkbox moves up. So when the `mouseup` event is fired the cursor is not anymore on the checkbox, that's why the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in pure CSS. You would need to bind focus event on JS.

Something like this:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input');

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.classList.add('focus');
});
```

And then change your CSS from `:focus` to `.focus`

Comment: I tryed your solution but it's same thing ([here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ciHCVsfNSdc9NgdozrN?p=preview))

Comment: @JeanJacques You are removing the class on `focusout`.

Comment: Yes because I want to hide the span when the input is not focused anymore

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: What I want to do is to display the message under the input when the input is focused and to hide it when the input is not focused anymore. If you go on the plunker on my post, it's working fine, but the problem is when the message is displayed (so the input is focused) then if I click the checkbox, it hides the message (it's what I want) but the checkbox is not checked. Hope it's clearer

Comment: Ok so the problem is that your `focusout` triggers as soon as you focus out and then it seems like `checkbox` is not being clicked. You can fix that by setting some timeout on `focusout` so you have the time to click it: `var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.classList.remove('focus');
    }, 500);`

Answer (score 0):

My solution for your question is attached here. This is a simple way. I have added JQuery code to it. You can try this code. I have written this code using JSFiddle. The link is given below:

[[https://jsfiddle.net/679g9p6p/1/][1]](https://jsfiddle.net/679g9p6p/1/)

If you want to hide the information when focus out from the textbox, then you can try this code given below:

[[https://jsfiddle.net/xxsL2e03/100/][2]](https://jsfiddle.net/xxsL2e03/100/)

Comment: Your solution doesn't really fit my needs, I want the span hiden if the input is not focused not when the checkbox value change. Thank anyway !